# Passing parameter by variable in $location search angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass variable in filter object to search relevant field but when I put object without passing variable like underneath it works fine:-

stock.controller.js

```
var vm = this;
vm.stocks = [
   {  
      itemName:'Peanut',
      labelName: 'Fortune nuts',
      cost : '$4'
   },
   {
      itemName:'Sandwich',
      labelName:'Coast Food',
      cost: '$10'
   }
]

vm.searchOptions = {itemName:vm.search};
```

stock.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.search"/>
<tr ng-repeat="s in vm.stocks | filter:{itemName:vm.search}">
    <td>{{s.itemName}}</td>
    <td>{{s.labelName}}</td>
    <td>{{s.cost}}</td>
</tr>
```

But in case when I get object from variable It won't work. Following I pass variable **vm.searchOptions** instead of writing it hard coded.

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in vm.stocks | filter:vm.searchOptions">
    <td>{{s.itemName}}</td>
    <td>{{s.labelName}}</td>
    <td>{{s.cost}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you have `vm.searchOptions = {itemName:vm.search};` then you need to use  `ng-model="vm.search.itemName"` to match the object.

Comment: What if I need to pass multiple parameters. @jcubic

Comment: The filter pipe documentation states that you can pass an object as parameter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter . It also contains an example passing an object. Can you please create a stackblitz/plnkr showcasing your issue, as your code looks ok so far